# Reading from text file to a JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, java.util.scanner

I followed a tutorial on how to read from a text file to a JTextField. It has been a few hours that I keep getting the same error when I run the program: 
**

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException  at 
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)  at 
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)     at 
>   demo.Demo.Read(Demo.java:26)  at 
>   demo.DemoSwing.main(DemoSwing.java:42)

**

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
 package demo;
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Demo {

 Scanner scan; 
static String Name, Surname;

 public void open() {

     try {
     scan = new Scanner(new File("C:/cygwin/home/James/Demo/src/team1.txt"));
     System.out.println("it is working"); }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
     System.out.println("it is not working"); } }

 public void Read() {   
      do
     {
         Name = scan.next();
         Surname = scan.next();
     } while(scan.hasNext()); System.out.println(Name + Surname);

 scan.close();
      } }




 package demo; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
importjava.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 public class DemoSwing implements ActionListener {
     private JTextField T = new JTextField(30);
     private JTextField T1 = new JTextField(30);
     private JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
     private JButton B = new JButton("View");
      // Static variable
     static String N, S;

     public DemoSwing(){
            f.add(new JLabel("Name"));    
T.setEditable(false);    
f.add(T);    
f.add(new JLabel("Surname"));   
 T1.setEditable(false);  
 f.add(T1);
B.addActionListener(this);    
f.add(B);

 // JFrame    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());    f.setSize(300,100);    f.setVisible(true);

     }
      public static void main (String[] args){
     new DemoSwing();

     Demo f = new Demo();
     f.open();
     f.Read(); } public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     if(e.getSource()== B)
     {
         T.setText(N);
         T1.setText(S);
     } } }
```

Comment: maybe to use `JTextArea` by using `JTextArea.read()`

Comment: What's with all the `>` in your code?

Comment: It seems you have single line in your file.

Add one more line and it should resolve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add if condition for your surname.

```
if(scan.hasNext())
         Surname = scan.next();
```

Add panel to a frame and access static values using class name while setting to text fields.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class Demo {

    Scanner scan;
    static String Name, Surname;

    public void open() {

        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("C:/team1.txt"));
            System.out.println("it is working");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("it is not working");
        }
    }

    public void Read() {
        do {
            Name = scan.next();

            if (scan.hasNext())
                Surname = scan.next();

        } while (scan.hasNext());
        System.out.println(Name + Surname);

        scan.close();
    }
}

public class DemoSwing implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField T = new JTextField(30);
    private JTextField T1 = new JTextField(30);
    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
    private JPanel p = new JPanel();
    private JButton B = new JButton("View");
    // Static variable
    static String N, S;

    public DemoSwing() {

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500, 500);

        p.add(new JLabel("Name"));
        T.setEditable(false);
        p.add(T);

        p.add(new JLabel("Surname"));
        T1.setEditable(false);
        p.add(T1);

        B.addActionListener(this);
        p.add(B);

        f.add(p);
        // JFrame f.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); f.setSize(300,100);
        // f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DemoSwing();

        Demo f = new Demo();
        f.open();
        f.Read();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == B) {
            T.setText(Demo.Name);
            T1.setText(Demo.Surname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the condition to the surname and the result appeared in the console thanks. Unfortunately the GUI don't show anything when I pressed the view button

Comment: I have done what you did and it works perfectly. I really thank you for your help :)

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the file you read has an unappropriate format. At least it seems, the scanner is not able to read a single token properly. To tell the reason for this, one would have to look at the file you want to read in.

A java.util.NoSuchElementException is thrown by Scanner.next(), if no more token exists. Since you check for this via scan.hasNext(), this must be happening in the initial loop of your do-while construction. If you check scan.hasNext() initially, there won't be this exception, but however you still won't get the desired result, because the loop would not run even a single time.

```
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        Name = scan.next();
        Surname = scan.next();
    }
```